# Menu burger animation toggle full page menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I need a menu burger that toggles on and off a full page menu but I can't get the coding to work together.

So I created both the Menu burger animation toggle and the Full page menu separately which work fine, now I dont know how to put them together, I have tried for ages but can't seem to make it work, can anyone help please?

**Here are the links to the codes:**

[**1. Menu Burger FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsrsrs/oLu0ywvs)

css:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
}

.border {
    position: fixed;
    background: #f9f8f3;
}

.top, .bottom {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}

.right, .left {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
}

/* End of -->> Body border */


/* Nav */

.c-hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}


.c-hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 12px;
  right: 12px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #262626;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #262626;
  content: "";
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -7px;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -7px;
}


.c-hamburger--htx {
  background-color: #f9f8f3;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span {
  -webkit-transition: background 0s 0.3s;
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
  -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
  -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
  background-color: #fafd37;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
```

[**2. Full Page Menu FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsrsrs/18qbxah6/)

css:

```
ul, li{
    list-style: none;
}

#yellowMenu {
    background: #fafd37;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 16%;
}


#yellowMenu a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2.1;
    font-family: 'FF_Super_Grotesk';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    transition: background-color 2s ease;
}

#yellowMenu a:hover {
    color: #e0e0d4;
    background: rgba(182,182,157,0.7);

}
```

Comment: is this what you are expecting?  http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/oLu0ywvs/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I undesrtood you right you want to click on burger to hide and show the menu.

If that's it is, just add the menu to your burguer fiddle, hide it with `display:none` and add this simple jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.c-hamburger').click(function () {
                $('#yellowMenu').toggle(); 
            });

        });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/oLu0ywvs/1/)**

Comment: Thanks Alvaro!, highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery `show()` `hide()` to do this ..

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

    for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var toggle = toggles[i];
        toggleHandler(toggle);
    };

    function toggleHandler(toggle) {
        toggle.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") || $("#testMenu").hide() : this.classList.add("is-active") || $("#testMenu").show();
        });
    }

})();
```

```css
/* Body border */

/* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbkOzrpmhUc https://css-tricks.com/body-border/ */
 body {
    padding: 0px;
}
.border {
    position: fixed;
    background: #f9f8f3;
}
.top, .bottom {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
.right, .left {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
}
/* End of -->> Body border */

/* Nav */
 .c-hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}
.c-hamburger:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.c-hamburger span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #262626;
}
.c-hamburger span::before, .c-hamburger span::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #262626;
    content:"";
}
.c-hamburger span::before {
    top: -7px;
}
.c-hamburger span::after {
    bottom: -7px;
}
.c-hamburger--htx {
    background-color: #f9f8f3;
}
.c-hamburger--htx span {
    -webkit-transition: background 0s 0.3s;
    transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}
.c-hamburger--htx span::before, .c-hamburger--htx span::after {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}
.c-hamburger--htx span::before {
    -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: top, transform;
}
.c-hamburger--htx span::after {
    -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: bottom, transform;
}
/* active state, i.e. menu open */
 .c-hamburger--htx.is-active {
    background-color: #fafd37;
}
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
    background: none;
}
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before, .c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}
#yellowMenu {
    background: #fafd37;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 16%;
}
#yellowMenu a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2.1;
    font-family:'FF_Super_Grotesk';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    transition: background-color 2s ease;
}
#yellowMenu a:hover {
    color: #e0e0d4;
    background: rgba(182, 182, 157, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<div class="border top"></div>
<div class="border bottom"></div>
<div class="border left"></div>
<div class="border right"></div>
<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx"> <span>toggle menu</span>

</button>
<nav id="testMenu" style="display:none;">
    <ul id="yellowMenu">
        <li><a href="">PROJECTS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/oLu0ywvs/2/)</kbd>

**EDIT:** 
For animating the hide and show use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

```
function toggleHandler(toggle) {
        toggle.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") || $("#testMenu").fadeOut() : this.classList.add("is-active") || $("#testMenu").fadeIn();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help, I have one question though, how can i make the full page menu fade in and out like the x button?

Comment: you can use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` , see my updated answer.